# failed to sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.2.0

Tags: kernel

**update 1**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2PgRKgeBo5ZbUpnQ0ZVdExpdkU/view?usp=sharing

after compile kernel and make install and 
can not boot , due to error VFS, can not mount fs
then try

```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k 4.2.0
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0
grep: /boot/config-4.2.0: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.2.0
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.2.0: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_mWhNBH/lib/modules/4.2.0/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_mWhNBH/lib/modules/4.2.0/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have unzipped the source, `cd` to the source dir and type as normal user:

```
export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=4
fakeroot make-kpkg clean
fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd kernel_image kernel_headers
```

Then install `../linux-image` and `../linux-headers` packages with `sudo dpkg -i`

However, mine  4.2.0 gives after grub:

```
kernel panic: not syncing: init killed
```

Maybe there is some incompabilites in initrd or elsewhere in tools with Debian Stretch with kernel 4.1.3.